# How to trick the ja, xor and jle instruction in gdb by setting flags?

Tags: gdb

I can "trick" the debugger into thinking that a `cmp` is setting the flag 0 by setting the `ZF` myself, and if there is a `je` after the comparaison, it will jump where I want.

Now my question is how do I set flag so that after a compare like:

`cmp    rcx,0xfcf` the `ja` will succeed and jump where I want?

I have the same question for the following sequence:

```
xor    rcx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
je     0x5629580fc209 <function+538>
```

How can I set flag for the `je` to be successful? Do I have to just set ZF?

Finally, what about

`jle`? What kind of flag have to be set?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set flag for the je to be successful? Do I have to just set ZF?

Yes.

> what about JLE ?

Likewise.

P.S. You could also use GDB `jump *0x5629580fc209` command without changing the flags at all.